# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on a for each instruction

Tags: jquery, syntax, foreach, identifier

I try to change a div value by using jquery functions. I make a sum of all the value of a json.
But I get the following errors :

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on google chrome
- SCRIPT1005: Expected '(' on IE
- that works fine on Firefox

All instructions are closed. No useless spaces. I try all solutions I find but nothing works. The error is on the "for each" instruction. 
Here is my code :

```
 var tab_prix = <?php echo json_encode($tab_prix) ?>;
function majTotal() {
            var sum=0;
            for each(produit in tab_prix){sum=eval(Number(sum)+Number(produit));}
            jQuery(\'#boutiqueExpress-total\').text(sum.toFixed(2));                    
        }
```

Thanks for helping ! (and sorry for my bad english :()

Answer (score 2):

See [the documentation for `for each ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in):

> Deprecated

and

> not widely supported by non-Mozilla browsers, not part of the ECMAScript standard

Use a `for ... in` loop instead.